# please i can not install auto sklearn. please i'm trying: !pip install auto-sklearn.in google colab. i have Python 3.10.12. i have windows ten

Tags: python-3.x, installation, runtime-error, metadata, auto-sklearn

My installation consists of Python 3.10.12 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to install a module using pip: `!pip install auto-sklearn` in google colab.

**Problem**:
It worked before but now fails to install;

Error:

```
Collecting auto-sklearn<br>
  Using cached auto-sklearn-0.15.0.tar.gz (6.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (67.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: distro in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.3.1)
Collecting scikit-learn<0.25.0,>=0.24.0 (from auto-sklearn)
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Could somebody assist with this error?